# What is the minimum version of Xcode required to test the app in test device (iOS 10.3.2)?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to the iOS development world. I have an app in the app store and there is one issue in the app. The app was developed long ago (around 5 years ago) and some features of the app stopped running in the latest update (10.3.2). I need to fix the issue but I don't know what is the minimum Xcode and OS I have to install in my MacBook to move ahead. I expect some suggestions from you.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you've to convert that code on to the latest version of language (Swift/Objective-C). And only then you can debug/run that latest code for iOS 10.3.2 on Xcode 8.3.2

Otherwise one more option is there to debug the issues on iOS 10.3.2 with converting the code, you can make an .ipa file of the old code and install it on iOS 10.3.2 and debug the issue with the help of Device logs.
Device logs you can find in Go to Xcode > Window from menu > Devices > Choose your device and click on the "View Device Logs" button.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use latest **Xcode Version 8.3.2** and install the different iOS version simulators, which you want to test the app.

But first I would suggest you to test on device version(10.3.2).